# Convert date to timestamp in bash (with miliseconds)

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, timestamp

I have CSV file in the following format

```
20170102 00:00:00.803,
20170102 00:00:01.265,
20170102 00:00:05.818,
```

I've managed to add slashes with

`sed -r 's#(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})#\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:#' file.csv > newfile.csv`

as below, to enable coversion to timestamp

```
2017/01/02 0:0::00:00.803
2017/01/02 0:0::00:01.265
2017/01/02 0:0::00:05.818
```

But after using

```
cat newfile.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date -d "$t" "+%s%N") ; done > nextfile.csv
```

I got :

```
2017/01/02 0:0::00:00.803,1499727600000000000
2017/01/02 0:0::00:01.265,1499727600000000000
2017/01/02 0:0::00:05.818,1499727600000000000
```

There's probably something wrong my data, but I'm too much of a beginner to be able to get missing values. It would be very much appreciated if you could drop me some sed/awk magic.Thanks!

EDIT: I need to have a timestamp with miliseconds, but all I got for now is just zeros (how typical)

Comment: I think telling us what do you want to have (an expected output) would help you to get an answer sooner.

Comment: Sorry! Please see the last line in the edited post

Comment: Please give a clear *example* of desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after but you could just parse the output without date to form the date stamp.

```
awk '{ print substr($0,1,4)"/"substr($0,5,2)"/"substr($0,7,2)" "substr($0,10,2)":"substr($0,13,2)":"substr($0,16) }' dates.csv
```

We use awk to pull out the extract of the line concerning day, month, year etc (substr function) and then use print to output the data in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

The original format is accepted by date as time stamp. You need not sed it. I believe you need `"date,milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"` in your output. Try this in bash.

generateoutput.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
  echo -n $line,
  echo `date -d "$line" "+%s%N"` / 1000000 | bc 
done < <(sed 's/,//g' $1)
```

where timestamp.csv is your file in original format.

bc - basic calculator, convert nanoseconds to milliseconds

Parsing large files line by line is bound to take time. 
If you need better performance, split your original file. I suggest doing this in a new directory

```
split -l 100000 -d <filename>
```

Run `generateoutput.sh` in parallel for each of this file and `tee -a` output

```
ls -l x* | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -n1 -P4 generateoutput.sh | tee -a output.csv
```

Comment: it did the trick! many thanks! I will upvote your answer when I get the rep! You really save me from wasting another evening on this :)

Comment: @krq If it worked and solved your problem, you can **accept** the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: hi again, thank you for your help, but unfortunately i need reopen this issue. my file is quite large (1.4 GB) and this script goes on for 24 hours and still needs couple of hours to finish. i need a quicker solution as i need to perform this activity quite often

Comment: You should split it into files with 10k lines each. Then run above script on each file. Use xargs for running it in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F',' '{ match($1,/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{3})/,a); 
           print mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]))*1000 + a[7] }' file.csv
```

The output:

```
1483308000803
1483308001265
1483308005818
```

Comment: I got an syntax error : awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,